# Store second value in cell

Tags: ios, swift

I need to store the id in `cell` as well as the text (to display in the listview). So how can I save 2 values in cell?

This is what I have

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sentence", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    //Get list
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
    if data != nil {
        var dataArray = JSON(data: data!)
        var item: NSMutableArray = []

        //Get IDs
        for (key, data) in dataArray {
            var name = data["dutch_sentence"]
            println(name)
            item.addObject(name.string!)
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = item[indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell

    }
    else{
        println("Out")
        return cell;
    }
}
```

But I want to send the id along too because I want to use it for the JSON array URL in the next view. So I would need something like:

```
cell.id = 2
```

To be able to call it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
How could I do that?

Comment: Don't use a table view cell as a store of data! It's a bad idea.

Comment: How else could I do it? When I click on the cell I want to send multiple values to the second view but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing data in you views is very bad design decision. You should save your data in array and then access it based on `indexPath.row`:

```
let ids = [5, 10, 20]

public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let id = ids[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And you were right, this way it looks so much cleaner!